# Node with --prof option creating multiple log files instead of one v8.log

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu

I am trying to profile my Node app with "--prof" option but I see that instead of one single v8.log file there are multiple files created with prefix like isolate-0x9582b40-v8.log, isolate-0xa1cab78-v8-6049.log,  isolate-0xa7ffb40-v8.log, isolate-0xb5900468-v8.log, isolate-0xb6200468-v8-6049.log .

I am having difficulty processing this files with Linux-tick-processor as I don't know which file to use for processing.

I am running with following config Ubuntu 12.4 Lts on Vm VirtualBox. Node version 0.12.0

Output of uname -a

Linux ubuntu 3.8.0-44-generic #66~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 04:04:23 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Output of node -v

v0.12.0

Answer (score 15):

I'm late to the party on this one, but if you invoke the profiler like this:

```
node --prof --no-logfile-per-isolate example.js
```

You will get a single file called `v8.log`. Then you can do stuff like this:

```
node --prof --no-logfile-per-isolate example.js && node --prof-process v8.log > example.v8log.txt
```

Note: this will result in a single output file, so if you **need** a file per isolate, you can use the `--logfile` option:

```
node --prof --logfile=foo.log example.js
```

This will still put the hexadecimal isolate identifier in the file name, but append the value you provided with the `--logfile` option, resulting in file that look like this: `isolate-0x103801e00-foo.log`, `isolate-0x104000000-foo.log` and so on.

If you don't like the `v8.log` file name, combine the `--logfile` and `--no-logfile-per-isolate` options:

```
node --prof --logfile=foo.log --no-logfile-per-isolate example.js
```

This will result in a single file called `foo.log`.

HTH. Enjoy!

--jsp

Answer (score 3):

I got my answer from another question posted by me

As of node.js v0.12 or io.js 1.0, the v8 logging is now per-isolate, so the filenames are of the format isolate--v8.log.
Thankz to @mscdex

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30600851/644949