# Starting Node with Forever and --prof option V8 Log file not created

Tags: linux, node.js, profiling, v8

I am trying to run my Node App using "forver" module , I also want to pass "--prof" option for profiling my app.
The command I am using is

> NODE_ENV=staging PORT=3000 NODE_CONFIG_DIR="/domains/serving/src/config" forever start -c "node --prof" -l /var/log/forever.log -e /var/log/forever_error.log -o /var/log/forever_output.log -a /domains/serving/src/bin/www

Or

> NODE_ENV=staging PORT=3000 NODE_CONFIG_DIR="/domains/serving/src/config" forever start -c "node --debug=3048 --prof" -l /var/log/forever.log -e /var/log/forever_error.log -o /var/log/forever_output.log -a /domains/serving/src/bin/www

Things work fine when running on my local machine , but the same command when executed on server multiple things fail

1) forever list command shows one process running but there is no process listening on port 3000
2) The profiler log file (v8.log) is not created I tried with find command

> sudo find / -iname "*v8*.log"

My local machine is Ubuntu

The server config is as follows
Output of following commands

> uname -e
>
> Linux MSSSKAMITMI 2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Sep 9 21:36:05 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
>
> node -v
>
> v0.12.0

If I run the node command without forever on Server and local every thing works fine the log files are created process listening on port 3000 and I can also make request and get response.

> NODE_ENV=staging PORT=3000 NODE_CONFIG_DIR="/domains/serving/src/config" node --debug=3048 --prof /domains/serving/src/bin/www

Comment: The best answer I found for this is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50892075/3487604

Answer (score 1):

As of node.js v0.12 or io.js 1.0, the v8 logging is now per-isolate, so the filenames are of the format `isolate-<hex isolate address>-v8.log`.

Comment: Yes you are right on my local machine log files are created with "isolate" suffix so I tried searching for log files with following command sudo find / -iname "*v8*.log" but with no luck the log files are not created on server. Any idea why this would happen,? even nothing is recorded in forever logs. And this happens only on servers Staging & Live

Comment: And few more question which file should I pass to the Linux-tick processor for analyzing? is there a tool for combining these files in to single files is it even recommended to do so or do I have to analyze each and every file separately? any place where more info is available will be very helpfull

Comment: Typically there will only be one isolate, but yes, you will have to analyze each one. You might try `find / -name "isolate*.log"`, but typically the v8 logs will be in the same working directory where the script was executed.

Comment: Yes I tried find with file arguments surrounded by stars , I don't know how they got removed from my comment's and question. At first I thought I might have forgotten the stars around "v8" in the question so I added in my comment but they also got removed from there also some formatting by SO. The file argument contained starV8star.log